# CoreData NSFetchedResultsController Empty Section Display

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I would like to show a fixed number of sections in a table view with a Fetched Results Controller as the data source.

If you image the contacts app where sections organised by the alphabet, it will not have a header for B if there are no contacts in that section, so the section headers you see are A then C.

I would like to display a section header in my table (for B), but without any rows. an empty section in effect.

Can NSFetchedResultsController do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot show a section header for a section with no rows.  That is not the way that a `UITableView` works.  There are ways to trick it (empty rows) but it would be against the intention of the UI design on the iPhone.

Comment: what do you mean by "against the intention of the UI design of iPhone"? We can simply make empty sections by not using NSFetchResultsController, will that be against?

Comment: You can do a lot of things.  However that does not make it right or look good :)  If the section is empty then there should not be a section header.  Look at the contacts app for inspiration.  If you don't have anyone with a last name that starts with X then the section header does not appear.